# Take array of strings and add to new array so all elements are length 8

Tags: python, list

For example if I have this list of strings:
['00000', '1101', '101', '001', '01', '101', '0011']

how can I add these strings together to a new array so that the length of each element is 8?

the result: ['00000110', '11010010', '11010011']

Comment: Show your own effort (code) properly formatted in the question.

Comment: @enke the `1` and `0` symbols are all in the same order, but regrouped into strings of length 8.

Answer (score 1):

Join all the strings together, then slice them into chunks of 8:

```
>>> a = ['00000', '1101', '101', '001', '01', '101', '0011']
>>> s = ''.join(a)
>>> [s[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(s), 8)]
['00000110', '11010010', '11010011']
```